(Marginal) Independence vs. Conditional Independence for a simple Bayesian network
I have a Bayesian network given by $p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(b)p(c|a,b)$ and I understand the derivation for $a$ and $b$ being (marginally) independent, but intuitively it doesn't make sense. If we are given $a$ then that tells us information about $c$ which would then give us information about $b$, would it not? Because although $a$ and $b$ are independent, $a$ is dependent on $c$ and $b$ is dependent on $c$?? But clearly this isn't right because $a$ and $b$ are independent. Can someone provide some more clarity on this seeming contradiction?


There is no contradiction.
Knowing the value for $a$ does add information about the distribution for $c$, but this alone does not add information about the distribution for $b$.
To gain that, you require adding knowledge about the value of $c$.

That is to say, when conditioning on a value of $a$, then $p(b\mid a)=p(b)$ although $p(c\mid a)$ is not necessarily equal to $p(c)$.
$$\begin{align}p(c\mid a) &= \sum_bp(b)p(c\mid a,b)\\p(b\mid a) &=p(b)\sum_cp(c\mid a,b)\\&=p(b)\end{align}$$
